# The array doesn't change and third scanf doesn't let me input anything

Tags: arrays, c, scanf

So this program is for an event reservation. I have been dealing with a few problems with this program that I cant think of a better solution. the program isn't complete. I only wrote the program for case A. I have explained the 2 problems below.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(){
int i, j, day, x;
char session[10];
int array[2][5] = {{0,0,1,0,1},{1,1,0,0,0}};
char response,ans,choice;


printf("\n**************** WELCOME TO NAT RESERVATION SYSTEM ****************");


printf("\n\nCHOOSE WHAT TO DO");

printf("\n\n\t\tA.\t\tBOOK THE THEATER\n");
printf("\t\tB.\t\tCHECK RESERRVATIONS\n");
printf("\t\tC.\t\tREMOVE RESERVATIONS\n");
printf("\t\tD.\t\tCALCULATE INCOME\n");
printf("\t\tE.\t\tEXIT\n");

printf("\n\nYOUR RESPONSE\t\t:  ");
scanf(" %c",&response);


switch (response){
  case 'A': printf("\n\nBOOK THE THEATER"); break;
  case 'B': printf("\n\nCHECK RESERRVATIONS"); break;
  case 'C': printf("\n\nREMOVE RESERVATIONS"); break;
  case 'D': printf("\n\nCALCULATE INCOME"); break;
  case 'E': printf("\n\nEXIT"); break;
}
```

first problem:
the third scanf doesn't let me input anything. Even if I change it to scanf (" %c",&ans); the same thing happens. I tried to remove the space in 2nd scanf, but when I do that it won't let me input anything in there but can input in the 3rd scanf (I hope you understand my question)

```
if (response == 'A'){

  printf("\n\nCHOOSE A DAY     :   ");
  scanf("%d",&day);
  j = day -1;

  printf("YOUR SESSION     :   ");
  scanf(" %c",session);    //WHEN I REMOVE THE SAPCE IT DOESNT LET ME INPUT ANYTHING

  if(session[0] == 'M'){
    i = 0;
  }
  if(session[0] == 'A'){
    i = 1;
  }

  if(array[i][j] == 0){
    printf("\n\nTHE SESSION IS AVAILABLE.\nDO YOU WANT TO CONFIRM THE BOOKING?(Y/N)   :   ");
    scanf("%c",&ans);  //3RD SCANF IF I KEEP A SPACE IN THE SECOND SCANF, I CANT INPUT ANYTHING HERE
```

2nd problem: the array[i][j] is 0 before booking so after they confirm the booking array[i][j] should be 1. as an example if I want to reserve morning session (i=0) of day 1(j=0). After I gave the inputs it shows that the session is available. Then I confirm the booking the array[0][0] should be 1. but again if I give the same inputs it shows the session is available. but I want it to display the session is not available.

```
    if(ans == 'Y' || ans == 'y'){
      array[i][j] = 1;
      printf("\nYOUR BOOKING WAS SUCCESSFUL!\n\n");
      main();
      
    }
  }
  if(array[i][j] == 1){
    printf("\n\nTHE SESSION IS NOT AVAILABLE.");
    printf("\nDO YOU WANT TO TRY ANOTHER SESSION?(Y/N):  ");
    scanf(" %c",&ans);

    if(ans == 'Y' || ans == 'y'){
      main();
      
    }else if(ans == 'N' || ans == 'n'){
      printf("THANK YOU! HAVE A NICE DAY!");
      exit(0);
     }
   }  
 }

  return 0;
 }
```

any help is appreciated. Thank you

Comment: The space in `" %c"` skips over whitespace, in your case the newline left behind by the previous `scanf`. You need to do the same in the last `scanf`, too.

Comment: Or better, `char line[128];` and for each input `fgets(line, sizeof line, stdin)` and then e.g. `if (sscanf(line, "%d", &day) != 1) { /* handle error */ }`. Using a *line-oriented* input function like `fgets` eliminates leaving characters unread in the input buffer than could cause your next input to fail. Using `scanf()` alone is full of pitfalls for the new C programmer. You only need 1 `printf` to output your entire menu...

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin If i change it like this, is it correct?  fgets(line,sizeof(line),stdin);
      sscanf(line,"%c",session);

Comment: `session` is an array. You use `sscanf` just like `scanf` except you are reading characters from your buffer `line` instead of `stdin`.-- why are you using `"%c` instead of `"%s"`? (or why is session an array and not `char`?)

Comment: If you are just looking at the 1st character, just use `fgets(line, sizeof line, stdin)` and then `*line` (equivalent to `line[0]` -- your choice) Then you could simply do `if (*line == 'M') ...` and so on. If you are scratching your head `*line` is `*(line + 0)` which is the same as `line[0]`.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin thank you so much for your help. yeah, I made mistake making the session an array, I didn't know how to use fgets(). Now I got an idea of it. Thank you again.

Comment: You may find this helpful for your [Menu Operation](https://paste.opensuse.org/5618455) Good luck with your coding. (it will allow the user to enter either UPPER-case or lower-case menu selections)

Comment: This is really helpful. I learned a lot of new things. Thank you!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at your code:

```
scanf(" %c", session); // ... WHEN I REMOVE THE SAPCE ...
```

The type of `session` is `char[]` (i.e. a char array) but you're storing only a `%c` (a single character) in session. Also, you've not given any ampersand which indicates the memory location.

Thus, change it to something like:

```
#define MAX 10
char session[MAX];
scanf("%s", session);
```

Another method is to use `fgets()` as indicated in the comments, but you may need to truncate the newline caused by it:

```
#define MAX 10
char session[MAX];

fgets(session, MAX, stdin); // it'll accepts whitespaces too!
session[strlen(session) - 1] = '\0'; // to avoid the extra newline
```

And you could keep the space now (`SESSION AVAILABLE` case):

```
scanf(" %c", &ans);
```

---

As the bottom line, you should always verify if the input was accepted correctly (i.e. to verify if the value returned by the `scanf` is exactly equal to the parameters passed in it) in order to avoid weird behaviors generated in the program.

Comment: Thank you. This worked properly. If you can, please help me with the problem with arrays.

Comment: @Nathali If you want to store M x N (rows * columns) array then use two nested loops (one for `i < M` and another for `j < N`) and initialize them.

Comment: Okay, I will try that. Thank you again.

Answer (score 0):

instead of using %c you can try %s in code or you can use gets(session);

```
  if (response == 'A'){

          printf("\n\nCHOOSE A DAY     :   ");
          scanf("%d",&day);
          j = day -1;
          printf("YOUR SESSION     :   "); 

          //scanf(" %s",session);    //try this one 
          //gets(session);          //or this one
         }

         if(session[0] == 'M'){
          i = 0;
          }
          if(session[0] == 'A'){
           i = 1;
          }

         if(array[i][j] == 0){
         printf("\n\nTHE SESSION IS AVAILABLE.\nDO YOU WANT TO CONFIRM THE BOOKING? 
        (Y/N)   :   ");
         scanf("%c",&ans);  //3RD SCANF IF I KEEP A SPACE IN THE SECOND SCANF, I CANT 
         INPUT ANYTHING HERE
```

Comment: Please do not advise to use the deprecated and unsafe `gets`, but only `fgets`.

Comment: @SergeBallesta yes it was my fault...i am a newbie so i am still learning and sharing knowledge to everyone...and thanku for correcting my mistake....